# Zooming in on procedural generated 2D terrain? (LOD)

Tags: procedural-generation, perlin-noise, level-of-detail, simplex-noise

My question is what methods are there to "zoom in" on a procedurally generated map using Perlin Noise (or Simplex).

If I have for example this generated[image]

and I wanted to "zoom" into that little red square I drew, how could I achieve something to the likes of this (ugly drawn) example:
[image]

While staying true to the terrain above? I have heard of 3D methods but couldn't find any meant for 2D maps.

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets define your noise function for terrain generation as `f(x,y)`.

`f(x / 2, y)` will set the zoom on the X axis to 200%

`f(x, y / 2)` will set the zoom on the Y axis to 200%

So, it's `f(x / zoom, y / zoom)` for your noise function.

This is true for any function in maths.

You can translate your output too.

`f(x - 100, y)` will move your output by 100 tiles right.

`f(x, y - 100)` will move your output by 100 tiles up.

To zoom by a factor of `z` around point `(a,b)`, you'd transform your noise function `f(a,b)` to `f((x - a) / z, (y - b) / z)`.